# Android - ListView in Swipe Refresh

Tags: android, listview, refresh, swipe

I have implemented a custom layout which covers the whole screen. Within this layout, the user can add several listviews to the layout at runtime. Additionally, I have a swipe-refresh for the fragment which holds the custom layout.

The problem is that **if I try to pull down the listview, the swipe-refresh is triggered** and I can't navigate in the listview. I tried to disallow interception via "`listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`" and hoped this would prevent the swipe-refresh from being triggered, if the listview is touched. Unfortunately that didn't work out (no behaviour changes at all). What can I do to actually use multiple listviews and a swipe-refresh?
An illustration of the problem:

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding an subclass "ScrollableListView extends ListView" and passing the SwipeRefresh reference to each ScrollableListView. Then, I enabled or disabled the swipeRefresh as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        this.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        switch (ev.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                analyzer.setRefreshSwipeEnabled(false);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                analyzer.setRefreshSwipeEnabled(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                        analyzer.setRefreshSwipeEnabled(true);
                        break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

"Analyzer" is my main activity, which has the following method

```
/**
 * Enables or disables the swipe refresh
 * @param isEnabled
 */
public void setRefreshSwipeEnabled(boolean isEnabled){
    swipeRefresh.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}
```